# SolrCloud on AWS ECS

Tags: solr, solrcloud

It seems that it is quite easy to run ElasticSearch on ECS:

http://blog.dmcquay.com/devops/2015/09/12/running-elasticsearch-on-aws-ecs.html

Is it possible to run SolrCloud on ECS and if so how might you go about it?

Answer (score 3):

I found an article from Zalando blog where they migrate from the classical master-slave Solr configurations to the new 
architecture  based on AWS ElasticLoadBalancer without the use of Zookeeper.

https://tech.zalando.com/blog/zookeeper-less-solr-architecture-aws/

Comment: The article is unrelated to deploying Solr on ECS.